# How do I evaluate this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, polynomials, roots, radicals

I have the following problem

> $$f(x)=\frac{(x+4)^{\frac12}(2x-x^2)(-\frac12(x+4)-^\frac{1}{2})}{x+4}, x>-4$$

Here's how far I got. I actually went a little farther, but after a couple extra steps I wasn't going anywhere.

1. Rewording the problem and including a constraint
   $$\frac{\sqrt{x+4}(2x-x^2)-\frac12(\sqrt{x+4})}{x+4}, x>-4$$
2. Creating an equality, multiplying both sides with the denominator, then subtracting $(2x-x^2)$ to the other side to square both sides $$(\sqrt{x+4}-\frac12\sqrt{x+4})^2=(-(2x-x^2))^2$$
3. Ending up with this, unable to continue
   $$\frac52x+10=(5x^3+4x^2-\frac32x+6)^2$$

I'm guessing I probably made some mistake from the start, and I'm guessing I need to work on simplifying roots and exponents better, like, instead of writing $x^2$ I write $xx$, I know things like that makes factoring, for example, easier. I'm still working on that.

Anyway, I'd appreciate some help here.

UPDATE: My mistake, I overlooked the directions. Apparently, I am to "write the expression as a single quotient in which only positive exponents and/or radicals appear"

Comment: What is the equation you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Robert Z, I included those parentheses because all terms are being multiplied together. I wanted to avoid writing $\times$ to indicate multiplication, so I will be including those parentheses again

Comment: @RobertZ I'm trying to solve the equation that is quoted

Comment: In the statement you wrote a function not an equation. No equal sign!!

Comment: BTW the rewording in 1) is not equivalent to the statement...

Comment: Ah, my textbook doesn't indicate it's a function. I just wrote it the way my textbook shows it. But i'll take your word that it's a function, so i'll add f(x)

Comment: What is the **complete** statement given by your book? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89964/discussion-between-lex-i-and-robert-z).

Comment: Caution ; You have transformed the (last) **product** by $-\frac12(x+4)^{\frac12}$ into a **subtraction**...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x+4}\cdot\sqrt{x+4}=x+4,$$ which for your previous problem gives $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+4}(2x-x^2)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x+4}\right)}{x+4}=\frac{x^2-2x}{2}$$ and for your new problem gives:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+4}(2x-x^2)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}}\right)}{x+4}=\frac{x^2-2x}{2(x+4)}.$$

Comment: Based on your answer, does this mean $x=2$? Because I went for another attempt and got $-\frac{(x+4)\frac12(2x-x^2)}{x+4}$ 


which led me to $x(\frac12x-1)=0, x=2$

Comment: @Lex_i See please better. Your expression it's exactly that I wrote in the first versa.

Comment: Okay good, thanks

Comment: @Lex_i You are welcome!